# Linear Transform T = A + B. When is Tw = Aw + Bw such that Tw is T restricted to the domain W

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

I have a question related to the Jordan-Chevalley Decomposition but I am also wondering about the general case.

I have that V is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T:V\rightarrow V
$linear. 
$T = D_{T}+N_{T}$ with $D_{T}$ diagonalizable and $N_{T}$ nilpotent and $D_{T}N_{T}=N_{T}D_{T}$.

I have already proved that if $W\subset V$ is T-Invariant then W is also $D_{T}$-Invariant and $N_{T}$-Invariant.

However, what I am struggling to prove is that if we were to restrict the domains of these functions then $T\mid_{w} = D_{T}\mid_{w}+N_{T}\mid_{w}$

Finally, in general, for arbitrary $T:V\rightarrow V
$linear with $T = A + B$, A&B also linear, when is it that $T\mid_{w} = A\mid_{w}+B\mid_{w}$ for $W\subset V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You struggle witj a triviality.

If $w\in W$ then 
$$ T|_W(w)=T(w)=A(w)+B(w)=A|_W(w)+B|_W(w)$$